# Grouping on DataTable using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have below DataSet with 3 tables,

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable table1 = new DataTable("table1");
table1.Columns.Add("ParentId", typeof(int));
table1.Columns.Add("ParentName", typeof(string));

        table1.Rows.Add(1, "Name1");
        table1.Rows.Add(2, "Name2");


        DataTable table2 = new DataTable("table2");
        table2.Columns.Add("ChildId", typeof(int));
        table2.Columns.Add("ParentId", typeof(int));
        table2.Columns.Add("ChildRowName", typeof(string));
        table2.Columns.Add("ChildColumnName", typeof(string));

        table2.Rows.Add(1, 1, "ChildRowName1", "Column1");
        table2.Rows.Add(2, 1, "ChildRowName1", "Column2");
        table2.Rows.Add(3, 2, "ChildRowName2", "Column3");
        table2.Rows.Add(3, 2, "ChildRowName2", "Column4");


        DataTable table3 = new DataTable("table4");
        table3.Columns.Add("ChildListId", typeof(int));
        table3.Columns.Add("ChildId", typeof(int));
        table3.Columns.Add("Attribute1", typeof(string));
        table3.Columns.Add("Attribute2", typeof(string));

        table3.Rows.Add(1, 1,"=", "Equals");
        table3.Rows.Add(2, 1, "=", "Equals");
        table3.Rows.Add(2, 2, "Cont", "Contains");
        table3.Rows.Add(2, 3, "<", "LessThan");
```

And I have below Class to populate List from Datatable

```
public class Parent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Child> childs { get; set; }

}

public class Child
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ChildList> items { get; set; }


}

public class ChildList
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ChildListAttribute> attributes { get; set; }

}

public class ChildListAttribute
{
    public string ColumnHeader { get; set; }
    public string Attribute1 { get; set; }
    public string Attribute2 { get; set; }

}
```

I am using below LINQ query, but Child is always zero.

```
from p in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                           select new Parent
                           {
                               Name = p["ParentName"].ToString(),
                               childs = from c in ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable()
                                        where p["ParentId"] == c["ParentId"]
                                        group c by c["ChildRowName"] into groupitems
                                                 select new Child
                                                 {
                                                     Name =      groupitems.First().Field<string>("ChildRowName").ToString(),
                                                     items = from item in groupitems
                                                                     select new ChildList
                                                                     {
                                                                         Name = item["ChildColumnName"].ToString(),
                                                                          attributes = from op in ds.Tables[2].AsEnumerable()
                                                                                       where item["ChildId"] == op["ChildId"]
                                                                                     select new ChildListAttribute
                                                                                     {
                                                                                         Attribute1 = op["Attribute1"].ToString(),
                                                                                           Attribute2 = op["Attribute2"].ToString(),

                                                                                     }
                                                                     }

                                                 }
                           }).ToList();
```

Can you please let me know, what is wrong with the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to add the tables to your `DataSet` before running your query, which you are probably already doing, but just want to make sure:

```
ds.Tables.Add(table1);
ds.Tables.Add(table2);
ds.Tables.Add(table3);
```

The children aren't populated because of your where clause:

```
where p["ParentId"] == c["ParentId"]
```

it should be:

```
where p["ParentId"].ToString() == c["ParentId"].ToString()
```

or

```
where (int)p["ParentId"] == (int)c["ParentId"]
```

This is because `row[column]` returns an `object`, not the value stored in the column.  So when you were comparing them, your were comparing if the objects themselves were equal, which they are not.  You want to test if the *values* of those objects are equal.

You need to do the same thing to get the attributes by joining the values, not the objects themselves.

```
where item["ChildId"] == op["ChildId"]
```

should be

```
where item["ChildId"].ToString() == op["ChildId"].ToString()
```

Let us know if that gets it for you.

Comment: Hi McCee, How can I include OrderBy in the grouped records in the above query?

Comment: You can add `orderby p.ParentName` (or whatever field you want to order on) between the `from` and the `select`.  The order of the commands goes: `from` then `group` then `where` then `orderby` then `select`.